# php login failure using AD LDS

Tags: php, ldap, adlds

i am trying to write a basic php script which connects to my AD LDS instance and authenticates a user, but i am getting login failure. the scripts are:

```
<?php
include("authenticate.php");

// check to see if user is logging out
if(isset($_GET['out'])) {
    // destroy session
    session_unset();
    $_SESSION = array();
    unset($_SESSION['user'],$_SESSION['access']);
    session_destroy();
}

// check to see if login form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['userLogin'])){
    // run information through authenticator
    if(authenticate($_POST['userLogin'],$_POST['userPassword']))
    {
        // authentication passed
        header("Location: success.php");
        die();
    } else {
        // authentication failed
        $error = 1;
    }
}

// output error to user
if (isset($error)) echo "Login failed: Incorrect user name, password, or rights<br /-->";

// output logout success
if (isset($_GET['out'])) echo "Logout successful";
?>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
    User: <input type="text" name="userLogin" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="userPassword" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

the authenticate function is as follows:
for the ldap_dn and ldap_host, i have put in the values for the distinguised name of the active directory and the primary instance of AD LDS server respectively.

```
function authenticate($user, $password) {
    // Active Directory server
    $ldap_host = "server";

    // Active Directory DN
    $ldap_dn = "O=mycompany,C=US";

    // connect to active directory
    $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);

    // verify user and password
    if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user, $password)) {
        // valid
        echo "<script>alert('valid');</script>";
        // check presence in groups
        $filter = "(userPrincipalName=" . $user . ")";
        $attr = array("memberof");
        $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        ldap_unbind($ldap);
if($result){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        // invalid name or password
        return false;
    }
    if($ldap)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

i still get a login failure. am i setting the ldap host or the ldap_dn incorrectly? if yes, what values do i need to set?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `ldap_bind` expects the given username to be a DN. And you are simply providing a username. I doubt that that works.

When I am doing LDAP-Logins, I always do a firt bind to get the DN from a username using either an anonymous bind or a dedicated user-account and as soon as there is the DN I use a second bind with the just retrieved DN and the provided password. That always works like a charm. And as I can define for myself which attributes I use in searching for the DN I can use whatever (unique) attriute there is to login.

I have created a [little gist](https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592) to show the basic concept.